# Commands in Sparklyr (R Studio)

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

What's the difference between the sdf_register and the copy_to command in sparklyr?

When do you use each command?

Answer (score 1):

`sdf_register` is a Spark specific function which registers `SparkDataFrame` in the metastore It doesn't involve data copying and is used for Spark interop.

`copy_to` copies **local** data to Spark. If used with `SparkDataFrame` it will collect and put it back to Spark.